# Prove: if the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent, then if we delete some of $A$ columns - $A$ rows will still be linearly dependent,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given a matrix $A \in M_{m\times n}$ ,  Suppose the rows of the matrix $A$ are linearly dependent.

**Prove/ Disprove**: If we delete some of the columns of the matrix $A$ then the rows of the matrix $A$ will still be linearly dependent.

$\  $

***My Attempt***:

as $dim C(A)  = dim R(A) =  rank(A)$

as $dim C(A) = dim{\left(sp  \{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n \}  \right)}$ where $\{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n \}$ is the vector space of $A$'s columns,

and $dim R(A)  = dim{\left(sp  \{r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m \}  \right)}$ where $\{r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_m \}$ is the vector space of $A$'s rows.

$A$ rows are linearly dependent, hence $$rank(A) < n$$

That means - $nullity(A) > 0$.

As Linear maps: $\mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}^m$ are equivalent to $m\times n$ matrices - then even if we delete some columns of the matrix $A$, then because $nullity(A) > 0$, deleting some columns won't make $nullity(A) =0$ - thus the matrix $A'$ (the matrix $A$ after deleting some columns) won't be a full rank matrix - and specifically there will be still be linearly dependent rows

Is that correct?

Comment: You're using the letter $A$ to mean two totally different things! You need to edit this, maybe saying the matrix is $A$ and using "$N$" for the other As.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't understand what do you refer by "the other as"

Comment: I think it's just a weird english construction that's making it hard to read.   "Suppose $A$ rows"  I think means "Suppose the rows of $A$".  However, I don't understand the proof, and in particular it is not true that deleting columns does not reduce the nullity.

Comment: If the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent, then $\text{rank}(A)<m$

Comment: @Callus - fixed it

Comment: @Jneven $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&5\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$. Rows are linearly dependent, but $\text{rank}(A)=2=n$

Comment: @ShubhamJohri $R_1$ and $R_3$ are linearly dependent if you delete any of the columns

Comment: I'm trying to counter your conclusion that $\text{rank}(A)<n$ if rows of $A$ are linearly dependent

Comment: $rank(A) + nullity (A) = n$. if the rows of A are linearly dependent - then $nullity(A) > 0  \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ rank(A) < n$

Comment: @Jneven No, saying the rows are dependent does _not_ imply the nullity is positive. That would be true if $m\ge n$. Look at the example Shbuham gave - the rows are dependent but the nulllity is $0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich you are correct.  but this isn't a contradiction to the claim/

Comment: @Jneven " but this isn't a contradiction to the claim" What? You said if the rows are dependent then the nullity is positive. In the example the rows are dependent and the nullity is zero.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich this is true.
thats why:


1. this argument is under the title: my attempt - which implies that mistakes are a possibility. especially as I ask: is my argument - which is - let it be marked as (*) : deleting columns won't make the matrix  rows to be e linearly independent.

I meant to say - this example doesn't contradict the main argument  - which is (*).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich this is not the first time you're comments to my posts are only about grammer  - which I appreciate as this helps me to improve and to write better questions. I would like to thank you for that. but as I am not a native English speaker - often my grammar is very wrong. I try to improve, but sometimes It is possible to be a little less "tough" as this creates a very unpleasant environment to talk about math

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given a matrix $A \in M_{m\times n}$ ,  Suppose the rows of the matrix $A$ are linearly dependent.
>
> **Prove/ Disprove**: If we delete some of the columns of the matrix $A$  then the rows of the matrix $A$ will still be linearly dependent.

If the rows of an $m \times n$-matrix $A$ are linearly dependent, then (by definition) we can write:
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i\vec A_{i*} = \vec o_n \tag{$*$}$$
where not all coefficients $\alpha_i$ are zero; $\vec A_{i*}$ denotes the $i$-th row of $A$ (as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$) and $\vec o_n$ is the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. But this implies that for the $j$-th coordinate, we must have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^m \alpha_i A_{ij} = 0 \tag{$\star$}$$
This holds for **all** coordinates of the rows, so for every $j$ with $1\le j \le n$.

If you delete $k$ columns ($k<n$), we still have $(\star)$  for all the remaining columns so $(*)$ still holds, but in $\mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.